# MySQL compare two columns value at the same row

Tags: mysql

I'm newbie in SQL, I wonder if its possible to compare the values of two columns in the same row(s) using MYSQL.

e.g. I have a table called "Table" with two columns "data_a" and "data_b" which both are (int)

I want to get "data_a" value bigger than "data_b" value .

| data_a | data_b |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 5 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 1 | 9 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't call your table "table", as it is a reserved word and can cause some confusion.

Have you read any documentation about querying? You should start from here [Query information](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/retrieving-data.html)

If you want to select all rows where `data_a` is bigger than `data_b` you can do it with

```
SELECT * FROM table where data_a > data_b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write query :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE data_a > data_b;
```